# Google Calendar doesn't work with FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I can't get a public Google Calendar to work with FullCalendar. I keep getting this error. Their documentation is out of date, which they have acknowledged on their GitHub page. If anyone knows a possible solution or an alternative, I'm all ears.

```
fullcalendar.js:1800 Uncaught TypeError: g[r.substring(...)] is not a function
at u (fullcalendar.js:1800)
at l (fullcalendar.js:1780)
at je.formatDate (fullcalendar.js:1514)
at m.et.format (fullcalendar.js:1407)
at e (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at u (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at l (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at je.formatDate (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at m.et.format (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at function.t.constructor.getEventTimeText (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: not sure what you think is out of date? I have got fullCalendar working with a public Google Calendar, right this moment, based on the instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ . You do need to have a recent version of fullCalendar and the gcal.js file, though.